# $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{\frac{1}{k+b}}^{\frac{1}{k+a}} \frac{1}{1+x}dx $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $\displaystyle 0\lt a\lt b\lt 1$

Then find

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{\frac{1}{k+b}}^{\frac{1}{k+a}} \frac{1}{1+x}dx $$

1. $\displaystyle \log{\frac{b}{a}}$
2. $\displaystyle \log{\frac{1+b}{1+a}}$
3. $\displaystyle \log{\frac{1+a}{1+b}}$
4. Infinity

My attempt
solved the integral. Stuckfurther . Need suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Oh yes, sorry for misprint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{1/(k+b)}^{1/(k+a)}\frac{dx}{x+1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\log\Big(\frac{k+b}{k+b+1}\frac{k+a+1}{k+b+1}\Big)=\log\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{k+b}{k+b+1}\frac{k+a+1}{k+a}\Big)$$

Now note that $$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{k+b}{k+b+1}\frac{k+a+1}{k+a}\Big)=\Big(\frac{1+b}{2+b}\frac{2+a}{1+a}\Big)\Big(\frac{2+b}{3+b}\frac{3+a}{2+a}\Big)...=\frac{1+b}{1+a}.$$

So option 2 is correct.

Comment: ups this answer was given already ...

Comment: U were little more busy typing

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\;\int_{1/(k+b)}^{1/(k+a)}\frac{dx}{1+x}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\log\left(\frac{k+b}{k+a}\cdot\frac{k+a+1}{k+b+1}\right)=\log\left(\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k+b}{k+a}\cdot\frac{k+a+1}{k+b+1}\right)$$

Open now the first factors in that product and realize it is a telescopic one (there's lots of cancellations).

Comment: U changed the integrand. Is that ok?

Comment: @singularity No, it's not. I missed that and I'm editing now. Thank you

Comment: well, you were fast: +1!

Answer (score 2):

hint: it's telescopic. after integrating you get:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\; ln(\frac{{k+A+1}}{k+A}) - ln (\frac{{k+B+1}}{k+B})
$$

Comment: But this didn't lead anywhere terms don't cancel.

Comment: you can actually split things up and realize they do.

Comment: Oh yes u r right